# Magento 2: How to Change shipping message?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, messages

How to change message?
see below image

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **override shipping.html in your theme** from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`.

**With Custom Theme:**

Copy vendor shipping.html file to your custom theme at `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html`

**Note:** Make sure you first delete static shipping.html from `pub/static` from `pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html`

Now change text at last `no-quotes-block` div to your custom message

```
<div class="no-quotes-block"><!-- ko i18n: 'Default Shipping Message Changed......'--><!-- /ko --></div>
```

Now flush cache and try.

**OR With Custom Module:**

Copy vendor shipping.html file to your custom module at `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

Now add requirejs-config.js at `app/code/Vendor/Theme/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html': 
                'Vendor_Module/template/shipping.html'
        }
    }
};
```

**Note:** Make sure you first delete static shipping.html from `pub/static` from `pub/static/frontend/vendor/module/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html`

Now flush cache and try.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: We need not `requirejs` at the time of overriding template file with a custom theme. we only need `requirejs` at the time of overriding template file with a custom module.

Comment: Hello prince above all steps are follow but its not working .plz help me.?

Comment: Please make sure you delete file from pub /static folder or run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` after changes.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see this sentence appears in two places:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

and

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/shipping-rates.html

Said that and depending on what you want to achieve you could:

#### Overwrite those files in your theme

By placing your own content in

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart/shipping.html

and

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart/shipping-rates.html

#### Overwrite those files in your extension

Create a requirejs-config.js in your extension

> app/code/Namespace/Mudule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

and place the following content

```
    var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Checkout/template/cart/shipping-rates.html': 
              'Namespace_Module/template/cart/shipping-rates.html'
        }
  }
};
```

Comment: why do you also need to create the requirejs? Is not enough override html file in theme?

Comment: They are **two different ways to do the same thing**. If you creating a theme, it makes more sense to modify the theme, if you are working on a custom module, it makes more sense to do it in your module so you can  pack all your changes at the end.

Comment: ok i didn't understand OR logic :)

Comment: I think there is even a way to change an html file using a layout xml. As I said, multiple ways to do the same thing, all depends on what suit you purpose better. :)

Comment: @LucaS and @diazwatson we need `requireJs` only when we override static html file with a custom module. It does not require at the time of overriding static files with a custom theme. So for this task, it's not required to add requirejs :)

Comment: @prince_patel david does not specify one thing or another that's why I explained both possibilities. Besides I thought it would be useful for anybody. :)